# Using enums with Entity Framework 4.1 code first

Tags: ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I am using entity framework 4.1 code first.

I have a `GrantApplication` class:

```
public class GrantApplication
{
   // Just some of the properties are listed
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public GrantApplicationState GrantApplicationState { get; set; }
}
```

`GrantApplicationState` is an enum and looks like this:

```
public enum GrantApplicationState
{
   Applying = 1,
   Submitted = 2,
   cknowledged = 3
}
```

Just before I go and add the grant application the database I set the grant application state:

```
public void Insert(GrantApplication grantApplication)
{
   // Set the current state to applying
   grantApplication.GrantApplicationState = GrantApplicationState.Applying;

   // Insert the new grant application
   grantApplicationRepository.Insert(grantApplication);
}
```

In my database I have a `GrantApplication` table with a `GrantApplicationStateId` that links to a `GrantApplicationState` table.

How do I get EF to add the state id from `GrantApplication.GrantApplicationState` to the GrantApplicationStateId column?  Is this possible?  And when I retrieve the GrantApplication object then it will need to be set as well.  Is this the way to do it or do I have to create  another property in my GrantApplication class called GrantApplicationStateId?

Comment: There may be an easier way to do this in EF4, but in our LINQ to SQL we use AutoMapper for things like this.  It's also good at taking multiple objects and mashing them into a single DTO, ViewModel, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create another property:

```
public class GrantApplication
{

   public int Id { get; set; }
   ...

   public int GrantApplicationStateId { get; set; }

   [NotMapped] // Perhaps not need
   public GrantApplicationState GrantApplicationState 
   { 
       get { return (GrantApplicationState)GrantApplicationStateId; }
       set { GrantApplicationStateId = (int)value; }
   }
}
```

EFv4.1 doesn't support enums at all - you cannot map them. This will change in EFv4.2.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out.  It doesn't seem to support alot of stuff.  When will EF v4.2 be out?

Comment: Nobody knows. Only first CTP is out so it can take 6 months or more.

Comment: Then when I need to go and set the state, would I then have to set grantApplication.GrantApplicationState = GrantApplicationState.Applying; and grantApplication.GrantApplicationStateId as well?  How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Still EF not support for Enums.. it will be on EF 5.0..check my try on here 
http://the--semicolon.blogspot.com/p/handling-enum-in-code-first-entity.html